# how to connect db with typeORM before set express server session?

Tags: javascript, database, express, typeorm, express-session

hello i am trying to use typeorm-store by save session / express-session

```
const sessionRepository = getRepository(Session); // db should be connected.
    app.use(
        session({
               secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET || "",
               resave: false,
               saveUninitialized: false,
               store: new TypeormStore({ repository: sessionRepository }),
               })
);
```

to use getRepository(), db connection should be connected before

so i must connect db before setting app's session
how can i do that?

this is my code

```
const app: Express = express();


const sessionConfig = async () => {
    try {
        console.log("✅DB connected");

        const connection = await createConnection();
        const sessionRepository = connection.getRepository(Session);

        app.use(
            session({
                secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET || "",
                resave: false,
               saveUninitialized: false,
                store: new TypeormStore({ repository: sessionRepository }),
            })
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`❗ Error: ${error}`);
    }
};

sessionConfig();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../client/build")));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    console.log();
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../client/build/index.html"));
});

app.use("/api", rootRouter);

export default app;

//controller login logic


export const postTrainerLogin: customMiddleware = async (req, res) => {

    const { username, password } = req.body;
   const userRepository = getRepository(User);

    const user = await userRepository.findOne({
    where: [{ name: username }],
    });

    if (!user) {
    return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    //@ts-ignore
   const passwordOk = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!passwordOk) {
        return res.sendStatus(400);
     }
    //@ts-ignore
   req.session.loggedIn = true;
   //@ts-ignore
   req?.session?.user = user;

    return res.status(200).json(user);
}
```

i made async function to connect db and set session before setting router

i expected my app working as

1. db connect
2. set session
3. router

and i expect i can  get session on my browser after login
but i cannot

in briefly

problem: icannot get my session after login

what i want to do solve it

connect db before set express server app